# git rm removing physical files even without -f

Tags: git, github, cmd, command, git-bash

I'm very new to Git so this might be obvious to someone.

Previously I was removing files (not physically, just from the repo) via `git rm <file>`.

Then for reasons I won't go into I had to do a force deletion, i.e. `git rm -f <file>`.

**The problem:** Since then, running `git rm` **without** the `-f` argument is deleting physical files as well, as though it's remembered that `-f` and is assuming it for each future request.

Why is this happening, and how can I stop it?

Answer (score 1):

As you've noticed, `git rm` removes files from both the working tree and the index. You need to use `-f` if the file in the working tree has changed on disk, but isn't the same as the version in the index. If they're the same, then `-f` is not needed.

However, if you want to retain the version in the working tree but remove the version in the index (thereby staging its removal from the repository), then use `git rm --cached`. That will leave the working tree version alone.

Answer (score 0):

the **git rm** command removes files from the working tree and from the index. The files being removed have to be identical to the tip of the branch, and no updates to their contents can be staged in the index.

With **-f option** we only override the up-to-date check of the file being removed against the file in the branch.

In your case I suppose earlier file(s) being deleted had different content then one in the branch, as a result, you had to use -f option with git rm command but now since they are in synch removal is working without the -f option.

Reference : [Git RM Doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm)

Comment: Hmm... OK, so how do I remove something from the index but not the physical file, regardless of diff? My situation is basically that a file was added before I realised it should have been .gitignore'd, so I need to remove it from the index, but not the file itself from the server!

Comment: I think your best bet is to move the file to be git-ignored temporarily.

Comment: In order to delete the file from repo but keep in local we can use --cached option of git rm command.